# BadFilterError: invalid filter: Only one property per query may have inequality filters (<, >=, >, <=)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to write ​a ​query​ ​in ​Python ​ ​using ​ ​the ​ ​datastore ​ ​API ​ ​to ​ ​fetch ​ ​no ​ ​more ​ ​than ​ ​5 ​ ​last ​ ​names​ ​of students​ ​with ​ ​GPA ​ ​greater​ ​than ​ ​and ​ ​equal ​ ​to ​ ​3.2 ​ ​and ​ ​birth ​ ​year​ ​less​ ​than ​ ​1998.
But, it returns error: `BadFilterError: invalid filter: Only one property per query may have inequality filters (<, >=, >, <=)..`
However, I am using the method mentioned in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_filter
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queries

Code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import datetime
import webapp2

class Student(db.Model):
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    gpa = db.FloatProperty()
    birth_year = db.IntegerProperty()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        student1 = Student(first_name = 'Alex' ,  last_name = 'Karev', gpa = 3.5 ,  birth_year = 1996 )
        student1.put()
        student2 = Student(first_name = 'Susannah', last_name = 'Walpole',gpa = 3.45, birth_year = 1997 )
        student2.put()

        self.response.write('<p>Student1 entity, key = %s</p>'
                             % student1.key())
        self.response.write('<p>Student2 entity, key = %s</p>'
                             % student2.key())

        q = db.Query(Student)

        q = Student.all()

        q.filter('gpa >', 3.2)
        q.filter('birth_year <', 1998)

        results = q.fetch(5)
        self.response.write('<p>Executing the query with fetch()...</p>')
        for e in results:
            self.response.write('<p>Found result: Last Name=%s'
                                % (e.last_name))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

And, when I am using GQL instead of datastore ​ ​API, I am getting the same error.
Code:

```
q = Student.gql('WHERE gpa > 3.2 ' +'AND birth_year < 1998 ' +'ORDER BY gpa ASC, birth_year DESC')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid filter: Only one property per query may have inequality filters (>=, <=, >, <)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568673/invalid-filter-only-one-property-per-query-may-have-inequality-filters)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391818/badfiltererror-invalid-filter-only-one-property-per-query-may-have-inequality?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but my Model is different, and I have tried them and it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
q.filter('gpa >', 3.2)
q.filter('birth_year <', 1998)
```

This is not a valid datastore query because it has more than one inequality filters, and returns error: `BadFilterError: invalid filter: Only one property per query may have inequality filters (<, >=, >, <=)..`
The results for the query must all appear on consecutive rows in the index and there is no possible index that could satisfy this query completely using consecutive rows.
So, I solved this problem by only using `q.filter('gpa >', 3.2)` and removing `q.filter('birth_year <', 1998)`, and using an if statement for to filter birth_year in the for look that prints the output:

```
self.response.write('<p>Executing the query with fetch()...</p>')
    count = 0
    for e in q:
        if e.birth_year < 1998:
            self.response.write('<p>Found result: Last Name=%s'
                            % (e.last_name))
            count += 1
        if count > 4:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use more than one variable with inequality filters using the datastore. If you really need to, you can filter using the 'begin' time only, and still get pretty accurate results.

```
calitem = self.appointments.filter("begin >= ", start).filter("begin <= ", end).fetch(limit=10)
```

Comment: I don't understand. There's no property called "begin". Thanks